# How do you make a pattern lockscreen in android studio?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I was just wondering if anyone could help me with this problem. I am trying to make a pattern lockscreen for my app in android studio, but I can't find the code anywhere and I can't find any video tutorials telling me how to make one. I am new to android studio and I am trying to make a simple app that just stores the user data and I am basically done with it, I just need a lockscreen. Thank you everyone for taking the time to read this, and also extra thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

There is an implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/geftimov/android-patternview). Or you can implement your own customview based on the code.

Comment: Thank you, Iv been looking for something like this for last couple days now!